# How to load partialview content and return to ajax result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: request,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $(".ad-image-wrapper").html(data.html);
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
```

and I want to load the whole html from a partial view that take some data from LoadPictureGallery. Anyway to write this properly ?

```
 public ActionResult LoadPictureGallery(string xxx)
    {
        var model = List<ABCClass>(){ blah blah};
        return new JsonResult() { html= XXXPartialView(model), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

UPDATED: What I need is [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

render a partialview to string and return it.

```
 public ActionResult LoadPictureGallery(string url, string alt)
    {

        var picture = new PictureModel()
        {
            ImageUrl = url,
            AlternateText = alt,
            FullSizeImageUrl = url,
            Title = alt
        };
        return new JsonResult() { Data = RenderRazorViewToString("_PhotoItem", picture), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };


    }

public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*Anyway to write this properly ?*" I think your question is a bit vague. If you don't get answers that fully answer your question you might need to reword it to better outline your problem.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to return a partialView

```
return PartialView(model);
```

And then use data itself

```
success: function (data) {
    $(".ad-image-wrapper").html(data);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [PartialViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in your action.

```
public PartialViewResult LoadPictureGallery(string xxx)
{
    var model = List<ABCClass>(){ blah blah};
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and just use the raw return data in your javascript

```
success: function (data) {
      $(".ad-image-wrapper").html(data);
}
```